# Create XML file with relative paths

Tags: python, relative-path

I have a list of absolute file paths. I want to create an XML file which contains a list of tags as: `<file path="relative path"/>` the relative path is the path between the XML file I'm creating and the location of the file, but I have no idea how to do this.

Is there any Python library which do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the `relpath` function of the `os.path` module:

```
from os.path import relpath

In [5]: os.path.relpath("test.txt",start="/")
Out[5]: 'Users/ebarr/test.txt'


In [8]: os.path.relpath("test.txt",start="/Var")
Out[8]: '../Users/ebarr/test.txt'
```

The first argument is the path and the second argument is where you want it to be relative to.

Comment: Thanks but I have another qestion: how can I now do the reverse operation; get the absolute path from the relative path I created ?

Comment: @user3328690 use `os.path.abspath`.

Comment: @ebarr when I use os.path.abspath it returns the absolute path from the actual file which is a python file what I expected is to get the reverse operation ; the absolute path from the xml file I created .. Thanks

Comment: @user3328690 I am confused, what do you mean "absolute path from"? An absolute path is absolute. It can only be from one place, which is "/".

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by checking out the [Element Tree XML API](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). This API implements a simple and efficient API for parsing and creating XML data.

Here is a link to the [updated documentation for the same Element Tree XML API (different Python version)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

As is noted on the second document, "The xml.etree.ElementTree module implements a simple and efficient API for parsing and creating XML data."

Finally, to deal with the relative path (as noted by @ebarr, and I quote):

"You want the relpath function of the os.path module:

```
from os.path import relpath

In [5]: os.path.relpath("test.txt",start="/")
Out[5]: 'Users/ebarr/test.txt'


In [8]: os.path.relpath("test.txt",start="/Var")
Out[8]: '../Users/ebarr/test.txt'
```

The first argument is the path and the second argument is where you want it to be relative to."

Comment: my problem is not creating the xml file.. my problem is how to obtain relative path as described ..Thanks for the answer

Comment: That makes sense. I was going to suggest the relpath function from the os.path module but note that ebarr has just posted a nice example to close off the rest of the issue.